# Install older drivers on newer Ubuntu?

Tags: drivers, 14.04, software-installation

Specifically, I have a DELL laptop where not all of the hardware works OOB with 14.04.

I would like to install Ubuntu 14.04, but install drivers DELL created for 12.04.

Being somewhat newbie to Linux, is it possible to install drivers for an older version of Ubuntu on a newer version?
If so, what is involved? What are the risks?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if they are debs then it will just work normally

Comment: I extracted the tar.gz and it looks like they are all .deb files...

Comment: then that will just install normally, also if this solved your problem it would be nice if you could mark it as such ;)

Comment: let me try installing and will do! Should be w/in the next 6-8 hrs